# A binomial distribution question with given $p$ and $n$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

The question asks that it is known that $20\%$ of the computer chips produced by a manufacturer are defective. The
Faculty of Arts & Science has just purchased $36$ new computers, each containing a chip
produced by this manufacturer. Approximately what is the probability that at most $10$ of the
computers contain a defective chip?

I've tried to solve this question by solving $$P(D \leq 10) = \sum_{x=0}^{10}{36 \choose x}(0.2)^x(0.8)^{36-x} = 0.911$$ which is not one of the answers below

(a) $0.9162$

(b) $0.3737$

(c) $0.7054$

(d) $0.02946$

(e) $0$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me `> pbinom(10,36,0.2, lower.tail = T, log.p = FALSE) [1] 0.9110872`

Comment: but it's not one of the options

Comment: For fun, why not check what happens if you change the 10 to 9 or 11? It could be a careless mistake on the part of the problem writer...

Comment: $9$ or $11$ doesn't  work

Comment: maybe when he says to approximate he intends that you approximate by a normal like in the central limit theorem. Your precise calculation is not too far off from letter a.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Answer (a) uses a (not very good) approximation, but must have been intended as the answer. None of the other answers is anywhere near correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. The answer key is using the normal approximation to binomial with a continuity correction, then rounding
to enter printed normal tables:

```
mu = 36*.2;  sg = sqrt(36*.2*.8)
z = (10.5 - mu)/sg;  z
[1] 1.375
```

Round up 1.38 to enter a printed normal CDF table and obtain Answer (a) 0.9162, which would have been an acceptable approximation--maybe 25 years ago.

```
round(pnorm(1.38), 4)
[1] 0.9162
```

Of course, the exact answer is obtained in R as 0.9111,
to four places.

```
pbinom(10, 36, .2)
[1] 0.9110872
```

With $p = .2$ and $n = 36$ this binomial distribution
(barely) meets some of the criteria for possible normal
approximation, but $p = .2$ is pretty far from $1/2,$
so normal approximation doesn't work so well--as the following figure illustrates.

[image: PDF of BINOM(36, .2) with 'Approximating' Normal Density]

```
x = 0:36;  pdf = dbinom(x, 36, .2)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=10.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, col="blue")
```